# Good gray font: Do metafont proofs have to look this bad?

Tags: dvi, metafont, xdvi

The old `gray` seen in [this question about gray.tfm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173290/metafont-book-problems-with-gray-tfm-and-displaying-experiment-2) has ... issues.

**shrink factor 8**:
[image: gray-sf8.png]

**shrink factor 9**:
[image: gray-sf9.png]

So, even when using shrink factor 8, which given the 4x4 pixel pattern used for pixels in `grayf.mf` seems like it should put 2x2 proof pixels on one display pixel, something goes wrong and we get rows of missing pixels, and when we use an unrelated shrink factor we get something much worse :-(

What gray font / xdvi flags should I use to get my metafont proofs to render correctly?

Comment: i believe that `gray.tfm` and its relatives were removed from the last tex live "because nobody ever uses it".  this seems to need to be rethought.

Comment: Are you sure this is not an issue in the viewer? Would be pretty odd behaviour to have such missing pixels produced by Metafont.