# Including Metafont proofsheets in LaTeX documents

Tags: metafont

How can I include the proofsheet of a letter produced by Metafont in a LaTeX document?
This occurs several times in the Metafontbook, e. g. on page 96 and on page 103.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As far as I know, those proofsheets are inserted in post-production.

Comment: @egreg -- confirmed.  that was the only viable method in 1984.

Comment: Knuth writes on his website that the volumes of _Computers and Typesetting_ were completely new built with modern technology in 2012/2013. This has perhaps brought a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the proofs are inserted in postproduction. However, one can produce a PDF file quite easily.

I copied `io.mf` in a working directory and ran

```
mf io
```

to get `io.2602gf`. Then I ran

```
mktextfm gray
mktextfm black
```

(see [Metafont Book - problems with gray.tfm and displaying "experiment 2"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173290/metafont-book-problems-with-gray-tfm-and-displaying-experiment-2)) and then

```
gftodvi io.2602gf; dvips io.ps -o; ps2pdf io.ps
```

to obtain `io.pdf`. Finally, the test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{io}

\end{document}
```

[image]