# Running metafont on a mac

Tags: mac, metafont

Can anyone do this with the latest OS and XQuartz? On my machine, XQuartz opens but displays nothing. E.g., after loading a file with

```
drawdot (35,70); showit;
drawdot (65,70); showit;
draw (20,40) .. (50,25) .. (80,40); showit;
```

I see a blank XQuartz screen.

Comment: Loading your example from a file, I too see nothing...

Comment: But it works sort-of if I enter it interactively, with Mavericks and latest XQuartz.  It is certainly flaky. Entering the snippet interactively, at the first showit an x-window opens but nothing is drawn. At the second, both dots were drawn. At the third the smile was added, but everything disappeared when I tried to resize the window. Frankly, I find it amazing that it works at all given that the instructions were written more than 20 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a work-around:

- First generate the two missing tfm/pk fonts you will need as explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173290/metafont-book-problems-with-gray-tfm-and-displaying-experiment-2?rq=1).
- Then save your MF program to a file, say `lawrence.mf`.
- Then, in Terminal, run `mf lawrence && gftodvi lawrence && dvips lawrence`.

This should produce a representation of your "font" as `lawrence.ps`.  If you open this with [Skim.app](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) you can set it to auto-reload when you re-run the command chain.