# Running Metafont interactively

Tags: linux, metafont

I tried the first experiment in chapter 5 in the Metafontbook: ran `mf`, typed
`\relax` and `drawdot (35,70); showit;`.  This opened a window entitled
Metafont, but containing nothing.  What's missing?  Using TeXlive 2020 on Linux.

PS. After adding `drawdot (65,70); showit;` I see both dots.

PS II. Which have now disappeared, after I changed window-manager workspace and back.

PS III.  Typing `showit;` before the first `drawdot` opens a window and allows the first dot to be seen, but after having switched workspaces and back, I haven't found any way of bringing the picture back, short of drawing something more and showing it.

Comment: I don't know but I can confirm I get the same behaviour, on a different distribution (TeX Live 2017 on macOS).

Comment: [I got a dot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPPou.png) when I tried using mf from tl2017, see image.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm getting confused. Here it works _sometimes_. I have now tried to run this snippet about 10 times, and the dot showed up 3 times... Does it work every time for you?

Comment: @mickep tried maybe 6 or 7  times and works every time (using X display on windows/cygwin 64 texlive)

Comment: I can't reproduce on Windows, but on Linux too...

Comment: It's amazing it still works at all, given that Knuth wrote those instructions in 1985.  On my macos system (with the optional x11 install), it takes a while to start the X11 Metafont window, and it seems to ignore the very first `drawdot`, but once the window is open, then every `showit;` produces an update to the screen.  And, as he goes on to explain in the next paragraph of ch.5, it's more usual to work from a file than by typing at the terminal.

Comment: I can confirm what @Thruston said: after `mf`, with the sequence of instructions `\relax` then `showit;` then `drawdot(35, 70);` and then `showit;` again, I see the dot. Something to do with the interface between the terminal and X11 I guess.

Comment: I've just had a strong sense of [deja vu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287827/15036)... I think I might vote to close this as a duplicate..

Comment: Why would you expect any difference between Linux and macOS?  if there's a bug in the interaction between the terminal and x11 it would affect them both the same.

Answer (score 2):

Until this is fixed (in X?), do the following.

Before drawing anything, type `openit;` to open a window.  If you have left the workspace and come back, type `openit; showit;` to redraw the current picture.  (Gleaned from the METAFONTbook p. 192.)